# Understanding code snippet for leet code most water question

Tags: javascript

I was doing container with most water question on Leetcode

Question:

> Given n non-negative integers a1, a2, ..., an , where each represents
>   a point at coordinate (i, ai). n vertical lines are drawn such that
>   the two endpoints of line i is at (i, ai) and (i, 0). Find two lines,
>   which together with x-axis forms a container, such that the container
>   contains the most water.
>
> Note: You may not slant the container and n is at least 2.

Question link: https://leetcode.com/problems/container-with-most-water

There I stumbled upon this solution

```
var maxArea = function(height) {
    let res = l = 0, r = height.length - 1, cur;
    while (l < r){
        cur = Math.min(height[l], height[r]) * (r - l);
        if (cur > res){
            res = cur;
        } 
        height[l] <= height[r] ? l += 1: r -= 1;
    }
    return res;
};
```

In the above code, I am unable to comprehend these two lines

`cur = Math.min(height[l], height[r]) * (r - l);`

and

`height[l] <= height[r] ? l += 1: r -= 1;`

as in why have they done `height[r]) * (r - l)`  and `height[l] <= height[r] ? l += 1: r -= 1;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the puzzle is to find the container that contains the most water. Given a container with 2 sides of different height, the area of water is capped to the lesser height, hence `cur (area) = minimum of (left height, right height) * length`.

The next step is to traverse the rest of the point to find any bigger area. So you have to stay with the higher side, and skip the shorter one, in hope that the next will be higher to maximize the area. hence `height[l] <= height[r] ? l += 1: r -= 1;` equates to `if left height is less or equal than right height, left move by one, right remains. if right is less, right move by one (towards the center), left remains`.

By doing so, the person is looking for a pair of tallest height, and when the x axis is done traversing, you would have stored the largest area.